# how to rate limit next.js server actions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel, next.js13

I am using server actions in next.js as per the documentation on [Server Actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions)

Everything is working well, but now I am looking to rate limit the server action, in order to prevent spam or attacks. I know how to rate limit nextjs requests, as this is laid out well in the documentation as well in a [rate limiting](https://vercel.com/guides/rate-limiting-edge-middleware-vercel-kv) guide.

But I so far didn't figure out how to rate limit a specific server action, as the server action posts to the root of the document, and rate limiting can only be specified by root path.
Does someone have an elegant solution for this?
I know I can create an api route and rate limit it, but I like the way to do things with server actions and would like to stick to this if possible.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you post your solution if you managed to get it working?

Comment: basically what was written in the answer did the trick

Comment: cool. i'll try that. never implemented rate limits before so am curious how the full solution looks like. post it below if you have it handy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can still use the same approach mentioned [on the docs](https://vercel.com/guides/rate-limiting-edge-middleware-vercel-kv). Because server actions will issue a POST request to the same route you're calling it from.

For example, if I call a server action while at a route of "/blogs/posts", the following middleware will run:

```
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.method === 'POST') {
    // apply your logic here
    console.log(request);
  }
}
 
export const config = {
  matcher: '/blogs/posts',
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that's the answer, forgot that I could filter by request method here

Comment: The docs are not clear on how to handle it properly. After handling it in the middleware you need to somehow get that response in your app so you could handle it and show some error to the users.